# WPF: NullReferenceException at Automation.Peers.ItemAutomationPeer.GetNameCore

Tags: wpf, automation, nullreferenceexception

I have a vexed problem and have spent a whole day for it, but still can't fix it.
I have a button on WPF UI,it is used to add a item to treeview, the code in xaml is below:

```
<Button Content="Create Item"  
                                        Command="{Binding NewItem}"
                                        Click="NewItemButton_Click"
                                        TabIndex="16"                                                                                           
                                        ToolTip="{Binding NewItemHelpText}"
                                        ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
                                        <Button.IsEnabled>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LogicalAndConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="CurrentItem" Converter="{StaticResource ItemCreationConverter}"/>
                                                <Binding Path="ControlMode" Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}" ConverterParameter="{x:Static local:Option.ReadOnly}"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Button.IsEnabled>
                                    </Button>
```

Sometimes, after click this button, will throw a exception,

```
> ERROR MyApplication.App [(null)] - Error in MyApplication
   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ItemAutomationPeer.GetNameCore()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdatePeer(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

this exception throwed randomly, after add some log to debug the code, I find that both NewItemButton_Click event and NewItem command execute to the end, I search my work solution, didn't find anything about Automation, I don't know why and where this exception throwed.

Can somebody help me? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably the same issue as reported and fixed here: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/122

So, you can either wait for .Net 8 (and probably an update to .Net Framework 4.8), or filter this exception out in `App.xaml.cs`:

```cs
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception.TargetSite?.Name == "GetNameCore")
    {
        // Ignore WPF exception that is fixed in .Net 8.
        // See: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/122
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Put the following line in the `Application` tag in `App.xaml`:

```xml
DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException"
```